# Clarification of Alter Self

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, polymorph

[Alter Self](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/alter-self/) description says:

> When you cast this spell, you can assume the form of any Small or
>   Medium creature of the humanoid type. If the form you assume has any
>   of the following abilities, you gain the listed ability: darkvision 60
>   feet, low-light vision, scent, and swim 30 feet.
>
> Small creature: If the form you take is that of a Small humanoid, you
>   gain a +2 size bonus to your Dexterity.
>
> Medium creature: If the form you take is that of a Medium humanoid,
>   you gain a +2 size bonus to your Strength.

I have two questions here.

1. I am a human and cast this spell on myself, do I get +2 size bonus on strength?
2. "If the form you assume has any of the following abilities, you gain the listed ability": What are the 'following' and what are the 'listed' abilities?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*I am a human and cast this spell on myself, do I get +2 size bonus on strength?*

Yes, that is on the spell description, it doesn't matter if your size was small or medium before casting the spell, as it is a [transmutation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Transmutation) effect. It's changing your body and part of the effect is that your strength is increased.

*What are the 'following' and what are the 'listed' abilities?*

The spell actually lists a few [special abilities](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities) that you could gain while under the effects of the spell, such as:

- darkvision 60 feet (example: [dwarf](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/half-orc/));
- low-light vision (example: [elf](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/elf/));
- scent (example: [bugbear](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids/bugbear/));
- swim 30 feet (example: [merfolk](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/uncommon-races/arg-merfolk/)).

If the form has any of these abilities, you gain them. You could even gain multiple abilities. For example, merfolk have both swim speed and low-light-vision.